# Combo box and check box in grid for editor in extjs 4?

Tags: html, css, extjs4

I design the grid in extjs with editor option. I need the combo box as a column and also need combo box when i edit the grid. The i need delete column as the check box column for both edit and normal grid. Its not working. can any one please help me

Here is the snippet:

```
this.mcmGridPanel = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
            height: 300,
            width: 690,
            title: 'Results',
            store: store,
            multiSelect: true,
            x: 0,
            y: 170,
            columns: [
                { xtype: 'gridcolumn', text: 'FlightNumber', sortable: true, flex: 1, width: 150, dataIndex: 'FlightNumber', hidden: true,
                    editor: new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
                                typeAhead: true,
                                triggerAction: 'all',
                                selectOnTab: true,
                                lazyRender: true,
                                listClass: 'x-combo-list-small'
                            })  
                },
                { xtype: 'gridcolumn', text: 'Origin',  sortable: true, width: 150, dataIndex: 'Origin',
                    editor: {
                        editor: new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
                            typeAhead: true,
                            triggerAction: 'all',
                            selectOnTab: true,
                            lazyRender: true,
                            listClass: 'x-combo-list-small'
                        })  
                    }
                },  
                { xtype: 'gridcolumn', text: 'Destination',  sortable: true, width: 150, dataIndex: 'Destination',
                    editor: {
                        editor: new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
                            typeAhead: true,
                            triggerAction: 'all',
                            selectOnTab: true,
                            lazyRender: true,
                            listClass: 'x-combo-list-small'
                        })  
                    }
                },  

                { xtype: 'datecolumn', text: 'StartDate', width: 80, dataIndex: 'StartAvailability', format: 'Y-m-d',
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        allowBlank: false,
                        format: 'Y-m-d'
                    }
                },
                { header: 'StartTime', text: 'StartTime', width: 60, dataIndex: 'StartAvailabilityTime',  
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'timefield',
                        format: 'H:i',
                        increment: 15,
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                },
                { xtype: 'datecolumn', text: 'EndDate', width: 80, dataIndex: 'EndAvailability', format: 'Y-m-d',  
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        allowBlank: false,
                        format: 'Y-m-d'
                    }
                },
                { header: 'EndTime', text: 'EndTime', width: 60, dataIndex: 'EndAvailabilityTime',
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'timefield',
                        format: 'H:i',
                        increment: 15,
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    text: 'Delete?',
                    header: 'Delete?',
                    dataIndex: 'delete',
                    width: 60,
                    renderer: function (value, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                        return '<center><input type="checkbox" id="Delete-' + rowIndex + '"/></center>';
                    },
                    handler: function() {

                    },
                    //disabled: true,
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'checkbox',
                        cls: 'x-grid-checkheader-editor',
                    }

                }
            ]
            });
```

I use the following code but Its not working. can any one please help me

Comment: What is not working ? Can you explain please.

Comment: Lorenz Meyer when i am double click on data in grid the combo box is not displayed.am using extjs4 copyright 2011. may be is this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the function that should display the combobox. In order to get this to work automatically, you shoud add the RowEditing plugin.

Try to add this

```
plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
        clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
        autoCancel: false
    })
],
```

Look at [this example in the doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/direct_grid_pt1). This will help you to get row editing work.

Is your column definition OK?
I got a combobox using this, but I'm aware this is not the full configuration needed:

```
{
    dataIndex: 'name',
    flex: 1,
    text: 'Name',
    field: {
        xtype: 'combobox'
    },
}
```

### Update

I experienced today a similar problem: my textfields were not rendering.

The culprit was unexpected:
I use a custom template, and the css rules needed for the display were missing. All I had to do was rebuilding the app using sencha cmd `sencha app build`. This completed the files of the template, and the field of the roweditor displayed correctly.

Chances are that this is also the case with you...

Comment: i already added . its only snippet. I need to get the combo box to display in editor in grid

Comment: @Suresh Hello, I ran in a similar problem today. I updated my answer.